# testNG, Java: How to combine a few Data Providers in one test?

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng, test-strategy

In the provided test I need to read the data from the `cell` in `Excel` and it works.

I would also like to add the functionality to store the `price` of the product in another `cell` in the `Excel`.

I've split, that into 2 data providers ('readData' and 'writeData'), however I'm unable to add the second data provider to the test or I don't how to do that.

Could you please advise how to combine both of them in 1 test?

`TEST`:

```
public class StandardProductPricingTest{

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    Page.initConfigurationAndLogin();
}

@Test(dataProviderClass = Utilities.class,dataProvider = "readData")
public void standardProductPricingTest(String product) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    HomePageActions home = new HomePageActions();
    GalleryPageActions galleryPage = new GalleryPageActions();
    PDPageActions pdPage = new PDPageActions();

    home.searchProduct(product);
    galleryPage.clickOnThePicture();
    String price = pdPage.readPrice();
    }
}
```

`DATA PROVIDER`:

```
public class Utilities extends Page {

@DataProvider(name = "readData")
public Object[] getData() {


    String data = excel.ReadCellData(1, 0);


    return new Object[] {data};

}
@DataProvider(name="writeData")
public Object[] writeData(String price){

    String sheetName = "standardproduct";
    String data = excel.getCellData(sheetName, 0, 2);
    System.out.println(data);

    int rowCount = excel.getRowCount(sheetName);
    System.out.println("total rows: " + rowCount);

    excel.setCellData(sheetName, "PDP Price", 2, price);

    return new Object[] {price};
}
```

}

Comment: A data provider is aimed at providing test data, only one can be set for each @Test. Why don't you add a call to this _writeData_ function at the end of the test or on the teardown method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Providers are use to pass the Test-Data into the @test .Please create a java member function to write the excel and call directly to your @test  instead of using it in /as data provider